# submitting html form via jquery ajax() and serialize()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to submit this form via jquery ajax, this is what I have made and it is not working. i.e. Form is submitting with page refresh and I am not seeing the response i.e. printing array on the same page.

**HTML**

```
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css' />
    <script  type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.10.2.js' ></script>
    <script  type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js' ></script>
        <form  id="form1" method="get" action="submit.php   ">
            <label>Name of Organization</label>
            <input type="text" name="OrgName" id="OrgName" class="textfield">
            <label>Address of Organization</label>
            <input type="text" name="OrgAddress" id="OrgAddress" class="textfield">
            <input type="submit" value="Register Organization">
        </form>
        <div id="response">ads</div>

    <script>
    $document.ready(function(){
        $("#form1").click((function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                    url:'submit.php',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#response").text(result);

                    }

            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**PHP (submit.php)**

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Comment: Try using  .serializeArray() , https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Just a note: if you want to send the values of the form through an `ajax` request, you can remove the `action="submit.php"` property/value inside the element `form`.

Comment: @Programer The answer given by CodingArt is not the correct answer, It doesn't even solve the problem you explain in the answer. A click event on `#form1` element doesn't do anything.

Comment: I know I changed click with submit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Use this - there have been a few syntax errors and the event has to be submit*

```
 $(function(){
        $("#form1").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                    url:'submit.php',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#response").text(result);

                    }

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: like **click((** <-- DOUBLE PARENTHESISC & **$document**

Comment: Yea don't *comment* the _problems_ in the code, it belongs in the *answer*

Comment: @dbf SORRY MATE KINDA BUSY

Answer (score 3):

```
 $document.ready(function(){

        $("#form1 input[type='submit']").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                    url:'submit.php',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#response").text(result);

                    }

            });
        });
    });
```

I your code $("#form1").click(.... does not have any meaning here... You want the event handler when you press the submit button. So I think If you take appropriate the selector then It might work perfectly

Comment: Bingo, now a bit of explanation? :) (and edit the explanation in your answer, not as a comment)

Comment: yaa sure..$("#form1").click(....  does not have any meaning here... You want the event handler when you press the submit button. So I think If you take appropriate the selector then It might work perfectly

Comment: One small error still though, `$document.ready` should be `$(document).ready` or just replace `document.ready` with the jQuery shortcut `$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form1").click((function(event){
```

change to

```
$("#form1").submit((function(event){
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in function `$(document).ready(function()`

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form1").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                    url:'submit.php',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#response").text(result);

                    }

            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Tried $(document) also changed click() to submit() but still no avail

Comment: @Programer what problem now you have remove form action attribute in html form

Comment: The response of @codingAnt works thats all i know :)

Answer (score 0):

2 remarks :

the submit function needs to return false to stop the normal post
 you can use the onsubmit attribtue in form instead of ready etc, like this

`<form onsubmit="$.ajax({url:'submit.php', type:'GET',data:$(this).serialize(),                    success:function(result){$("#response").text(result);});return false;" id="form1" method="get" action>`